# GraphQL Arguments in GatsbyJS from context in gatsby-node.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm having trouble filtering items in a GraphQL query in GatsbyJS. I thought I could create key-value pairs in the `context` section of `createPage` (like `currentDate` and `minusFiveDays` below) and then use them as arguments in page components, but it doesn't seem to be working.

In `gatsby-node.js`:

```
        const currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const minusFiveDays = moment()
            .subtract(5, 'days')
            .format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        console.log('DATE', minusFiveDays); // this logs correctly

        result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
            createPage({
                path: node.frontmatter.slug,
                component: someContentTypeTemplate,
                context: {
                    // Can the names passed in here be accessed in
                    // graphql queries, prefixed with a dollar sign?
                    currentDate: currentDate,
                    minusFiveDays: minusFiveDays,
                },
            });
        });
```

In my `src/pages/someContentType.js` file:

```
// TODO: this query doesn't work. No matter what condition I try to use
// for $minusFiveDays, it doesn't affect the output. The query does work in
// graphiql when I hard-code a string there like "2018-11-01".
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query($minusFiveDays: Date) { // this is the key from the file above
        allMarkdownRemark(
            filter: {
                frontmatter: {
                    content_type: { eq: "some_content_type" }
                    start_date: { ne: null, gte: $minusFiveDays }
                }
            }
            sort: { order: ASC, fields: [frontmatter___start_date] }
        ) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    frontmatter {
                        created_at
                        slug
                        title
                        start_date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                        end_date
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Even if I hard-code it like this, it doesn't work, so the context doesn't appear to be getting passed into the component's GraphQL query:

```
                context: {
                    currentDate: currentDate,
                    minusFiveDays: "2018-11-01",
                },
```

This *does* work in GraphiQL:

```
{
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {content_type: {eq: "some_content_type"}, start_date: {ne: null, gte: "2018-11-01"}}}, sort: {order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___start_date]}) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                    frontmatter {
                        created_at
                            slug
                            title
                            start_date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                            end_date
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think my syntax must be wrong, but I'm new to GraphQL and Gatsby, and there are no error messages. **EDIT:** there is an error message when I change `Date` to `Date!`: `Variable "$minusFiveDays" of required type "Date!" was not provided.`

Comment: Where does `Date` come from in `someContentType.js`?

Comment: It's defined in the first two lines of the top code snippet above.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. Do you mean the `Date` in the arguments? I think that tells graphql that it should expect a date there instead of something like a string. I also tried `Date!` to make it a required field, but it says "Errors: Variable "$minusFiveDays" of required type "Date!" was not provided." It isn't getting passed in.

Comment: Could it be that your moment format `('YYYY-MM-DD')` is not playing nicely with your graphQl format `"DD MMMM YYYY"` ?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, because it works in graphiql when I hard code it (example: https://gist.github.com/j127/038d832291cf69fffc5b1b90557f10cd ). The error message is that the variable isn't provided. I tried changing it so that the formats match, but the error message doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your template is inside the **`src/pages`** directory.

`*.js` files inside `src/pages` will automatically be built into pages, including your template `someContentType.js`. This means Gatsby generates this page automatically for you, on top of the custom `createPage` calls you made in `gatsby-node.js`.

However, when Gatsby generates this page automatically, it doesn't know about the context you passed in via `createPage`. This is why it doesn't work.

Moving your template outside of `src/pages` will likely fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because the value you are getting from this line:

```
const minusFiveDays = moment().subtract(5, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

is not a `Date` type. From a little trial in console, it appears to be a string.

If instead change it to:

```
$minusFiveDays: String!
```

It might work, without seeing your project I can't tell for certain.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but the error message changes to: `GraphQL Error Variable "$minusFiveDays" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "Date".`

Comment: In graphiql, I can filter with the date as a string: `start_date: {ne: null, gte: "2018-11-01"}`. It must be parsing dates out of the strings that are passed in.